# How to use Scanner methods when scanning a String?

Tags: java

I have a text file that consists of a few lines of a small list of integers separated by spaces. I was to scan the first line, and do something for each integer that is in the first line.

```
    String lineString = textScan.nextLine(); //scans the first line of the text file.
    Scanner Line = new Scanner(lineString); //scans the String retrieved from the text file.

    while (Line.hasNextInt())
    { //do stuff 
    }
```

So I have a scanner (textScan) that scans the first line of the text file and then saves it as a String. Then I have a second scanner that scans through the String to check if the values in it are integers.

But the while statement doesn't allow me to use "Line.hasNextInt" to scan through the String! So how do I scan through the String line to figure out if it has integers or not?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, my mistake in wording. The loop will infinitely run, and so I tried creating a print statement before the loop: *System.out.println(Line);*, and it prints out this error:

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match
>   valid=false] [need input=false][source
>   closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decim al
>   separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive
>   suffix=][nega tive suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

The odd thing is that it compiles fine?

The input file:

```
5 4 4 3 5 
4 2 2 5 3 
5 2 5 2 3 
5 4 3 2 3 
5 4 2 2 5 
4 4 2 4 2 
3 3 5 3 5 
5 2 4 5 2 
4 4 5 4 2 
2 4 3 5 2 
3 3 3 5 3 
2 4 5 3 4 
3 5 5 4 3 
3 4 2 2 4 
5 5 5 4 4 
3 4 4 4 5 
3 2 4 2 4 
5 4 4 2 4 
5 3 5 2 3
```

Comment: *"doesn't allow me to use"* What do you mean? Is there a compilation error message? An exception when the program runs? Please edit the question to include the specific problem you're having.

Comment: ***Exactly*** what **format** does each line have?

Comment: Also consider if regular expressions are better suited for your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issue.
You need to use  `Line.nextInt()` inside the loop to move the cursor.

If not, the Line always points to the beginning and the loop never ends.

**To use it correctly, call nextInt() so it picks up the next token:**

```
while (Line.hasNextInt())
{ 
     System.out.println(Line.nextInt());
}
```

**Infinite Loop:**

```
while (Line.hasNextInt())
{ 
     System.out.println("Infinity");
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're right! That does seem to be the problem! That makes sense.

Does there happen to be a way to remove move the cursor onto the next object (or remove the object from the string list) without printing it out?

Comment: Yes, just call `Line.nextInt();` method. Don't have to assign or save its value or print it anywhere. inside the loop, as the first statement you can call Line.nextInt() and then go ahead with your processing.
As long as `nextInt()` is called inside the loop it will work. Can you accept the answer and close out the question, if its resolved?

Comment: Oh how interesting, I had no idea you could do that! Thanks, that's two questions solved! :P Oh, and sorry I just left your un-accepted a little bit longer to bring exposure to my comment here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary need to solve that problem using scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myString = "This is not int";
    String myInt = "123456";
    int copyOfInt = 0;
    try {
        copyOfInt = Integer.parseInt(myInt);
        System.out.println(copyOfInt);
        copyOfInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
        System.out.println(myString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not int");
    }
    // Put this in a loop and you can keep doing stuff
}
```

Or you can use FileInputStream, which I think is better. 
Here is an example:

```
    try (FileInputStream readFile = new FileInputStream(refFile);
            InputStreamReader readIn = new InputStreamReader(readFile, "UTF8")) {
        BufferedReader ReadBuffer = new BufferedReader(readIn);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = ReadBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            // Search my string of interest 
            if (line.equals("Potential/V, Current/A")) {
                while ((line = ReadBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Get data after string of interest 
                    // Use createDataType_1_Object() to get my data
                    myDataArray.add(createDataType_1_Object(line));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: I think Scanner is much simpler here. I would have preferred one scanner and the other using regex or split of string. That will be much simpler than anyother solution.

Comment: I agree with you, I think it's more of a personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry misunderstood your question earlier in the case you have multiple integers in the same line you can split them using a delimiter and still use a single scanner:

```
String yourFilename = "filename.txt";

File file = new File(yourFilename).useDelimiter(" ");
Scanner sn = new Scanner(file);

while(sn.hasNextInt()){
// Do your work here
}
```

Comment: This would read all lines of the file. What @Guy wants is to read just the first line and then parse that line alone for int. So either 2 Scanners are needed, or one scanner to read the input and second he needs to use split on that String to get it.

Answer (score -1):

In while loop you need to put boolean expression:

```
while(Boolean_expression)
{
   //Statements
}
```

<s>You don't input `String` into Scanner class as a parameter.
Scanner class takes `InputStream source`.</s> ->Thank you for your comments, my mistake.

Comment: What does the Java API mean by producing a Scanner from a specified String, then? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Thomas
This is actually valid.
`Scanner(String source)`
Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
You can try this sample code, if needed.
`Scanner Line = new Scanner("5 4 4 3 5");`
       `while (Line.hasNextInt())`
         `System.out.println(Line.nextInt());`